# Page.UICulture -- How do I retrieve the Two Letter UICulture Code?

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization, culture

In ASP.NET webforms, when setting **UICulture="en"** in the @Page directive, a **Response.Write(Page.UICulture)** returns the string **"English"** instead of the two letter language code **"en"**.

Is the the only way to return the two letter language name by using this?

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName
```

Or is there a better / more elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly I don't know of any better way to do it.

You could create an extension method, but that might be overkill:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetUICultureCode(this System.Web.UI.Page page)
    {
        return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
    }
}
```

Then in your page you can access it with **this.GetUICultureCode()**