# Get uiculture using server expression tag in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, currentuiculture, uiculture

Can I get uiculture of a page using server expression in aspx page defined in `globalization` tag?

```
<%= Page.Uiculture %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I pound out way to do it.. If you have any pls post.

```
alert('<%= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture %>');
```

[This page helped.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171973/page-uiculture-how-do-i-retrieve-the-two-letter-uiculture-code)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can get by this way

```
<% = Page.UICulture %>

<% = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture %>
```

both works fine.